# load/require not defined when running js on Java 7 + rhino

Tags: java, javascript, dom, rhino, domparser

I have a Java program which creates a ScriptEngine (rhino) and launch a JS file.
In my JS file I need to use the DOM-Parser (I know there are other ways of parsing xml on rhino but I need to use the DOM).
So I need to load sax.js,  dom-parser.js, dom.js in my js (like xmldom guys  [suggest](https://github.com/jindw/xmldom/wiki/How-to-use-xmldom-in-non-node.js-JavaScript-platforms-like-Rhino-or-SpiderMonkey)).
But it turns out that the rhino version that is being used in Java 7 is not a full version and doesn't support load or require.
I tried the solution suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11080037/java-7-rhino-1-7r3-support-for-commonjs-modules) but load/require still doesn't work.

I tried evaluating the script in the right order but it causes a bug in xmlDom like described [here](https://github.com/jindw/xmldom/issues/88).

Here is my current Java program:

```
public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException, MojoFailureException {

Reader saxScript = new InputStreamReader(XmlToJSONConvertor.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("sax.js"));
Reader domScript = new InputStreamReader(XmlToJSONConvertor.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("dom.js"));
Reader domParserScript = new InputStreamReader(XmlToJSONConvertor.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("dom-parser.js"));
Reader rhinoScript = new InputStreamReader(XmlToJSONConvertor.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("rhinoConvertor.js"));
    try {
    if (!inputXMLFile.exists()) {
    this.getLog().info(inputXMLFile.getName() + " doesn't exists");
    }

    Context cx = Context.enter();
    Scriptable scope = cx.initStandardObjects();
    scope.put("xmlInput", scope, IOUtil.toString(new FileInputStream(inputXMLFile), "UTF-8"));
    final Require require= new Require(cx, scope, new ModuleScriptProvider(), null, null, true)
    cx.evaluateReader(scope, saxScript, "sax.js", 0, null);
    cx.evaluateReader(scope, domParserScript, "dom-parser.js", 0, null);
    cx.evaluateReader(scope, domScript, "dom.js", 0, null);
    String jsonResult = (String) cx.evaluateReader(scope, rhinoScript, "rhinoConvertor.js", 0, null);
    Context.exit();
```

So how do I get my JS to use DOM and run it on rhino?

Comment: Can you update your answer if you implement the changes laid out here to setup CommonJS support in Rhino?: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30355409/263986

Comment: I used the full version rhino (rhino-1.7R4.jar) as suggested and did managed to use CommonJS. I'll update the full solution soon.